# Why is a boost optional reference not a wrapper around a T*?

Tags: c++, memory, pointers, boost, reference

Since `boost::optional<T&>` is already a specialisation, why isn't it just implemented as a wrapper around `T*`? This would allow it to occupy less space, since there is no need for the `m_initialized` boolean.

Comment: Please show me the requirement for a pointer to be 8 bytes or any other size come to that

Comment: Yeah I guess this is a bit architecture specific. However the point still stands if you just put `sizeof(T*)` there instead: isn't the `m_initialized` boolean wasteful?

Comment: Dont worry about space until it becomes an issue - running your code on a box with 128GB - who cares

Comment: Well it's not just about running out of space! It's about the expense of copying these things, and cache performance. Also, I'm not really asking because of a specific piece of code, I'm more interested in the broader question of `T*` vs. `boost::optional<T&>`.

Comment: Again - dont sweat the performance until it becomes an issue - let the compiler optimize it - programmer are the worst at optimizing their own code. I work in an environment where micro seconds matter - we ignore all this stuff until it is a problem

Comment: I'm not sweating it. My preference is already for `boost::optional` because of the safety. However in explaining this preference it would be nice to be able to say that it's a nice example of the C++ zero overhead principle post-optimisation. I don't understand why it's implemented this way and I imagine there's a good reason for it that would be a nice piece of knowledge for me and the stack overflow community. If you don't know don't hide behind that by brushing off my interest as illegitimate. I never said anything to indicate I was prematurely optimising.

Comment: Since boost is multi platform the answer is worthless in a general concept and since you are looking without a actual problem then you are prematurely optimizing ;-)

Comment: AFAICT in Boost 1.48, `optional<T>` is not specialized.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm having trouble finding the specialisation too. However, if it's not specialised, how is it possible that optional references have rebind semantics for `operator=` instead of assigning to the object like normal optionals do? Also, you can't construct a reference into a given storage address or explicitly destruct it, or can you?

Comment: Actullay, in my version (1.48) there is no specialization of `optional` for references. Instead, an lot of internal classes are specialized for references. Particularly, the type holding the actual value is `typedef ::boost::detail::make_reference_content<T>::type internal_type`, and that _is_ specialized for references.

Answer (score 7):

Since [boost 1.61](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_61_0.html) optional is optimized in the case of references.

The release notes mention :

```
sizeof(optional<T&>) == sizeof(T*)
```

hence it's certainly implemented as a pointer in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Probably so because an uninitialized `boost::optional<T*>` object must be distinct from `boost::optional<T*>` initialized with `NULL`, e.g. *this function can return no value, a `NULL` or a non-`NULL` pointer*.

Why don't you use a plain pointer in this case with `NULL` indicating no value. No need to add more complexity on top of that with `boost::optional<>`. I mean, it is easy to make things bigger or more complex but it's hard to make them any better.

Comment: He didn't give you a problem that you should solve, he asked a question about boost::optional. He may have very good or very bad reasons to use it, but that's beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood... I don't see the relevance of `boost::optionals<T*>`.

Comment: +1 Your answer is spot-on. You could have added, for the benefit of mozza314 et al, that nobody's had the time or will (yet) to optimize especially the case of a reference, so that it just uses the general implementation for the highest levels. But anyway, the comment of cubic that you shouldn't consider what the OP's real problem might be is of course best ignored: you did exactly right, IMHO, and I agree with the advice.

Comment: If you think this answer is spot on perhaps you can enlighten me because it sounds like a total red herring to me. `optional<T*>` and the difference between that optional being uninitialised and storing a null pointer is totally irrelevant. I asked about `optional<T&>` and as you are probably aware a reference is not nullable.

Comment: agree, this doesn't answer the question. The question was about `optional<T&>`, this answer is about `optional<T*>`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `boost::optional<T&>` is not a specialization. If you look at the code, you'll see that it does do some tag-based dispatch to customize behavior for reference types, but the `boost::optional_base<T>` class template itself is not specialized.

However it is still a legitimate question as to why this space optimization is not implemented. Possibly because it *isn't* specialized, the job is that much harder, I don't know.

The question as to why you'd prefer `optional<T&>` over a raw pointer is a completely separate one, so feel free to ask it separately...